# If traveling with relativistic speeds can observer find space denser than normal?

Tags: special-relativity, soft-question, speed, doppler-effect

I know that outer space contains few particles per cubic meter, but I am curious if travelling that fast for our brave traveller all of these particles will look like a dense pool of molecules.
And more, thanks to something like the Doppler effect, will these incredibly long waves propagating through space will become observed as much shorter for our observer?

Comment: w/r to what frame do you define “normal”?  By the principle of relativity if the traveller is in an inertial frame the density he or she measures is “normal”.

Comment: maybe I wasnt clear enough. "normal" means our point of view, the average person like you or me, who is looking at stackexchange site now ;-)

Comment: ...and what waves are you referring to?

Comment: let me rephrase: what reference frame (if not the observer frame) are you talking about?  If it's the observer frame, everything is already "normal".